# What does the command 'set `who am i` do in Linux?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I was trying to set the shell variables to the output of `who am i` command by using the command as typed in title, but the results are a bunch of shell information and codes as far as I can figure out. What happened? 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Aside from the fact that setting the shell variables to the output of `who am i` makes no sense, I suppose the output was identical to the output of `set`. If not please add the output to your question.

Comment: @kos you are right about the output, but their difference is `63c63
< PIPESTATUS=([0]="0")
---
> PIPESTATUS=([0]="127")
99c99
< _=-alF
---
> _=i`when I compare two output files. I was following the tutorial in [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gh0Ms3YRQzM )  where `who am i` was used. It seems `who am i` is replaced as `who` in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @user285586 `who am i` works fine on Ubuntu 14.04. Why is `PIPESTATUS` mentioned? The command given doesn't use any pipes. Is that actual command you ran, or did you run something else?

Comment: That video is too long. I ran the command you reported literally and nothing happens (expected since whatever you type after `set` `set` won't output). So which command are you running exactly?

Comment: @muru `who am i` does not work (no output) in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Instead, `who` works as expected. I did not run other commands, and `PIPESTATUS` appeared both in the output of `set `who am i`` and `set` commands.

Comment: @user285586 Then something's wrong with your Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, because `who am i` works fine for me.

Comment: That explains it. Because of your problem with `who am i`, `set \`who am i\`` is interpreted the same way as `set`, `set \`\``, `set \`echo -n\`` or whatever.

Comment: @muru Is there a method to repair this problem?

Comment: We don't know what's the problem yet. How are you running this command? SSH? Local terminal?

Comment: @muru Local terminal.

Comment: `am i` are the two parameters that can be given  to the `who` command, as stated in `info coreutils 'who invocation'`. I also followed the tutorial in the video, tried to alter that `set` command in various ways, but I still couldn't recreate your error or anything close to it.  If your `who` command is really buggy, you may want to attempt reinstalling the coreutils package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`

Comment: works like charm on my box! the actually program is `who`. The `am i` is just a flag to the `who`.

Comment: @user285586 Please [edit] your question to include all the troubleshooting information in the comments so others can help you faster. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`set 'who am i'` stores the result of `who am i` in $1.
it can be used to display/store username and time-stamp in shell scripting.